# HTTP 405 error when connecting to spring-security auto-generated log-in page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I cannot connect to the auto generated spring security log-in page.  According to the documentation, including the following lines in your security-context.xml will have Spring generate an html log-in form and redirect the user to it when trying to connect to the specific URL:

```
<http auto-config="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/management-console" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager ... />
```

Here is the rest of my configuration.  Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/context/applicationContext.xml <!-- I am importing my security-context.xml in here -->
        <param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Security Configuration -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/management-console</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried importing the security-context.xml directly in the web.xml, but I still see the error.

After deploying my application, I can connect to each my specified urls without issue.  However, when I try to go to localhost:{port}/{appName}/management-console, the filter chain redirects me to /spring_security_login (as expected).  However, I see an "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported" error once I am forwarded and the following comes up on the console (spring-mvc is the name I gave to my servlet):

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound            | No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/InternalManagementViewer/spring_security_login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc' |
```

I have seen this error before when I miss declaring a POST/GET mapping in the controller. According to the documentation, I should not have to include such a method in my controller to handle the /spring_security_login mapping. From what I have read, spring is supposed to know to return the auto-generated log-in html page.

Just to see what happens, I declared a method in my controller to handle the /spring_security_login mapping.  Since the function returns void (because I do not know the local view name of the generated html log-in page), it looks for the resource named "spring_security_login.jsp", which is not explicitly created in my project, and thus I get an "HTTP resource not found" error.

I'm stumped on this one and could really use a hand. Thanks a lot for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `springSecurityFilterChain` filter to all URLs:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

`springSecurityFilterChain` is an entry point for all Spring Security features. So if this filter is not applied to some URL then you will not be able use Spring Security there (in this case handle /spring_security_login URL).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your suggestion worked.  

  I should note (in case anyone has the same error in the future) that I noticed I was having a "silent" xml-parsing error, where my container was unable to locate the javax.servlet.Filter class.  I imported that jar and was still seeing the issue, until I tried your suggestion.

Thanks again!